# Spring dependencies not resolved in Spring Tool Suite

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I started a tutorial in Spring.

I downloaded Spring Tool Suite, then created the `demo` project offered as a template, then I created a class and wrote the following code:

```
package com.example;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class WhateverIWant {

    @RequestMapping("/hi")
    public @ResponseBody String hiThere() {
        return "hello world!";
    }
}
```

The problem is that `ResponseBody` and `RequestMapping` are not recognized.

I right clicked on the project and did a `Run As` and then `mvn clean` and `mvn install`, but still the dependencies are not recognized.

My `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

How can I make Spring Tool Suite be aware of the dependencies?

Comment: can you share the pom.xml?

Comment: I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that ResponseBody and RequestMapping are not
>   recognized.

You are missing the following dependency in your `pom`.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add spring-web jar

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
       <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
```